# Merge multiple text to text file based on filename batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

hi guys i have some problem with my batch. i want to create batch that can merge multiple text file to one text file but it must based on 2 first character of the filename.
so it will be like this
file :

- 01i043.prn
- 01i053.prn
- 02i043.prn
- 02i053.prn

expected output is like this :

- 01i043.prn + 01i053.prn = pvj.prn
- 02i043.prn + 02i053.prn = ip.prn

i have some script like this

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.prn) do (
       for /F  "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%a in ("%%f") do (
         echo %%a>> pvj.txt
       )
)
```

but its make all of my .prn file merge, can someone give me complete solution
thanks before and sorry for my bad english ^_^

Comment: So - will there only be 2 files starting 99....prn - or can there be many? Are the numbers 01..12? Could they be ...am and ...pm? How do you want those combined? Where do 'pvj' and 'ip' come from? Are there any other (apparently) random names for the combined files? Since they appear to be some variety of timestamp, will there be a new set the next day - and how do you want to treat the existing `pvj/ip`.prn - or do you want .txt??

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocaL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
for %%f in (*.prn) do (
   set file_name=%%f
   for %%C in (!file_name:~0,2!*.prn) do (
     for /F "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%a in ("%%f") do ( echo %%a>>%%Cpvj.txt )
   )
 )
```

Comment: What about exclams `!` in the text? And empty lines ?